# Asp.net mvc: DropDownList Virtualization, unable to select data from dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, virtualization

I am creating a web app in which I am using kendo's component,

I have a kendo dropdownlist/Virtualization, which works as per [This](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist/virtualization)

here is how it looks

[image]

the problem is when I try to click on any of these record, the click don't work

below is my code

> CSHTML

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("SecondApproverId")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .MinLength(3)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })

    .Height(290)
    .AutoBind(false)
    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Custom()
            .ServerFiltering(true)
            .ServerPaging(true)
            .PageSize(80)
            .Type("aspnetmvc-ajax")
            .Transport(transport =>
            {
                transport.Read("GetSecondaryApproval", "User");
            })
            .Schema(schema =>
            {
                schema.Data("Data").Total("Total");
            });
    }).Virtual(v => v.ItemHeight(26).ValueMapper("secondaryApproval"))
)
```

> Controller

```
public ActionResult GetSecondaryApproval([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    return Json(SecondApprover().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SecondApprover()
{
    return CreateList(ResourceProvider.GetUser(Convert.ToInt32(Id)).SecondApproversNameList(Id).Tables[0], "userId", "ApproverName", "-1"); ;
}
```

And on initialization I am getting the below error from my controller in network panel

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem, but I think it is important to tell everyone how I found my solution,

actually css property called `Transition` was preventing click event

I simply added the below code

```
<style>
    * {
        transition: none;
        -webkit-transition: none;
        -moz-transition: none;
    }
</style>
```

and now it works

Comment: Where exactly was this changes made? @Ibrahim Shaikh